# Can Google or other search engines (robots) scan SSL/HTTPS pages/websites?

Tags: search, ssl, https

Well, the title pretty much states the question...

Comment: It would be helpful to use the description space to add context.  What specifically are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSL secures the communications, it does not provide content access mechanisms.

As long as there is no password/authentication restricting access to the pages, there's no reason a search engine would be unable to index them.

Comment: Authentication and authorization are orthogonal concerns to transport-layer security (encryption). You can browse a site over HTTPS without having to enter a password; likewise, you can browse a site over HTTP but be forced to enter a password for the privilege.

Comment: -1. SSL does provide content access mechanism in the form of client-side SSL authentication.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

They may choose not to spider over HTTPS, or they may choose to rate lower those sites that are available only over HTTPS, or they may choose to do any number of things. But they can certainly spider the Web over HTTPS just as easily as your browser can view a single Web page over HTTPS.

Comment: What is the most likely behaviour for the popular engines that you might observed? Do they normally choose to record and display HTTPS pages in their search results? I can see Google is displaying HTTPS://PayPal.com, but is showing the Wachovia bank without the SSL even though their site is secured too.

Comment: Google may be looking for the `Strict-Transport-Security` response header. You will find that Paypal sends that header while Wachovia does not.